# Query timestamps in Google Sheets looking for specific date but ignoring the time

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a range of data with a timestamp in the first column. I want the average of a particular column (AF) for a specific date, regardless of what time the timestamp has.

The formula I'm currently working on looks something like this but it returns an empty result set although I can see the data is present.

```
=query(ImportedData1!A1:AF, "Select avg(AF) where A = date '2019-04-08' label avg(AF) '' ", 0)
```

What am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=query(ImportedData1!A1:AF, "Select avg(AF) where toDate(A) = date '2019-04-08' label avg(AF) '' ", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(ImportedData1!AF:AF, 
 INDEX(SPLIT(ImportedData1!A:A, " "), ,1) = DATE(2019, 4, 8)))
```

[image: 0]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(FILTER(ImportedData1!AF:AF, 
 LEFT(ImportedData1!A:A, 10) = "08/04/2019")))
```

[image: 0]